# How do I populate Wicket @SpringBeans in Scala?

Tags: spring, scala, wicket

I have a Wicket `Page` with a `@SpringBean`

```
class ScreenDetailsPage(parameters: PageParameters) extends BasePage(parameters) {
    @SpringBean(name = "screenDAO") protected var screenDao: DAO[Screen] = null
    assertNotNull(screenDao)
```

and I find that the @SpringBean is not populated. It makes no difference if `screenDao` is val or var, protected or private.

Looking up the tree I find that the constructor of `Component` (indirectly) initialises `@SpringBean`s on behalf of its subclasses, but then the assignment to null is uninitializing it. But the assignment is required by Scala.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
class ScreenDetailsPage(parameters: PageParameters) extends BasePage(parameters) {
    @SpringBean(name = "screenDAO") protected var screenDao: DAO[Screen] = _
    assertNotNull(screenDao)
```

I have not tried this, but am also thinking about starting a Wicket/Scala project, and saw  [this blog entry](http://agileskills2.org/blog/2010/06/19/getting-started-with-scala-spring-hibernate-wicket/), which might be useful in other ways as well.

The relevant section quoted from that blog is

> In addition, note that the field is assigned to an underscore (_), which tells the Scala compile to NOT initialize, but leave it at the default state (null in this case). This is required for the injection to work. If you assign it to null explicitly, you
>   will overwrite the Spring bean as the injection will occur before the constructor of MyPage is executed.

Comment: I love this place, who'd have thought I could have an answer to this in 15 minutes on a Saturday!

Comment: Now the only slight annoyance is that this only works as var rather than val, where the Java code does work even when the fields are marked as final. But I'll gratefully take what I can get, as it's far cleaner than my previous InjectorHolder.getInjector.inject(this) fix.

Comment: BTW - I'm having a lot of fun with Scala and Wicket. I'm only just beginning to code my Pages in Scala, but so far it has been excellent for testing.